# Initialization of structs in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I stumbled upon this weird struct implementation(from a big project) and I wanted to know the difference between this one and the normal one and why is it even implemented this way :

```
struct Sabc{
   Sabc()
   {
       A = 0;
       B = 0.0f;
   }
   int A;
   float B;
}
```

Why not just :

```
struct Sabc{
   Sabc()
   {
      int A = 0;
      float B = 0.0f;
   }
}
```

Or why not even this way:

```
struct Sabc{
   int A = 0;
   float B = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: The second way is not the same as the other two. The first uses a constructor to initialize members, the last provides defaults for the members. The second way has no member.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question for "C/C++". They are different languages, and there would be different answers for each. Please choose a language and [edit] your question.

Comment: Have you tried the second approach? `A` and `B` will cease to exist after the constructor has run.

Comment: And none of them is valid C, så why include that tag?

Comment: My bad, I removed the C tag

Comment: It might be good to know that the difference between class and struct is only that struct defaults to public for all members, while class defaults to private.

Comment: It's not weird. First and last are more or less equivalent, second is wrong. The last way was not possible with older C++ versions (don't remember which one).

Comment: I see good to know thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a struct with two members, explicitly overrides the default c'tor and initializes both members 0 and 0.0f:

```
struct Sabc{
   Sabc()
   {
       A = 0;
       B = 0.0f;
   }
   int A;
   float B;
}
```

Declares a struct with no members, and explicitly override the default c'tor, within it declare two local variables, initialize with values, and on c'tor return, variables go out of scope and are deleted:

```
struct Sabc{
   Sabc()
   {
      int A = 0;
      float B = 0.0f;
   }
}
```

Declares a struct with two members, and implicitly default initialize to 0 and 0.0f, only compiles in C++:

```
struct Sabc{
   int A = 0;
   float B = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Is the first initialization of struct widely used in C++ ?

Comment: It's really a matter of style, I personally prefer to use the last example, if it's a simple struct/class (In C++ there is little difference between a struct and a class, and the same rules apply there too)